# Programmatically load battery saver screen on Samsung J3

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, batterymanager, power-saving

I want to load **battery saver** menu from an activity programmatically on **Samsung J3** device with android **lollipop**. I have tried the following snippet:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_BATTERY_SAVER_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

but it throws **ActivityNotFoundException**.

any other way to programmatically load battery saver screen on J3 device?

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
     * Activity Action: Show battery saver settings.
     * <p>
     * In some cases, a matching Activity may not exist, so ensure you safeguard
     * against this.
     */
```

See google documents, your devices can not support this activity.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_BATTERY_SAVER_SETTINGS

Comment: what's the way to programmatically load battery details screen on samsung j3?

Comment: Not all phones have this setting

Comment: Or for summary usage

`Intent batterySaver = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_POWER_USAGE_SUMMARY);
startActivity(batterySaver);`